# How to select processes by command name when using ps in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ps

In Linux, I use `ps -C command_name` to select processes of specified command name. But it doesn't work in Mac OS X. I read the the man page of ps carefully, but just can not find any option to do this.

So anyone know if there is way to select specified processes by command name when using ps in Mac OS X?

Comment: Try `ps | grep command_name`

Comment: `ps | grep command_name` will include the `ps | grep command_name` itself.

Comment: `ps | grep command_name | grep -v grep` is the simple solution for that. /cc @oli

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, it seems you can't really do this without using grep as an aide or piping/shelling to a second linux command to help out.  If your attempting to do this by launching a process from some other language, e.g. Java, you may need to avoid using any shellisms and hence need to do it one command.  Therefore consider [pgrep](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pgrep.1.html) as an alternative.  e.g.  To list all java processes:

```
pgrep java
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to filter the output of `ps` is to use a tool that can generally filter input, `grep`.

To do this, we just *pipe* the output of `ps` into grep, like so:

```
oliver@cloud:~$ ps | grep bash
31131 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
```

In case you're listing **all** processes, you'll quickly run into an issue though:

```
oliver@cloud:~$ ps a | grep bash
 2729 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep bash
31131 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
```

Now it returns `grep` itself as well! How do we fix it?

Simply by using `grep` *yet again*, to filter out the excess result:

```
oliver@cloud:~$ ps a | grep bash | grep -v grep
31131 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
```

Comment: Thanks, @slkch already give this answer, but I'll accept yours anyway.

Answer (score 1):

<- OSX -> To get PID of running binary called Humans by matching binary aka COMMAND name.

helios:~ TimberWolf$ killall -s Humans

-> Just the number

helios:~ TimberWolf$ killall -s Humans | tr -d [:alpha:][:space:]-

-> Use PID with ps command for more refined details such as priority of the binary.

helios:~ TimberWolf$ ps `killall -s Humans | tr -d [:alpha:][:space:]-`

Comment: from man killall : -s  Show only what would be done, but do not send any signal.

Comment: I use a modification of your command: `killall -s Humans|awk '{print $3}'`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Here is a solution, not totally satisfying:

```
ps -p `pidof <command_name> | tr ' ' ','`
```

This does not work all the time (e.g. when the command name is actually a call to an interpreter), and it is rather ugly. I hope it can give ideas and yield better solutions!